# Cropping out whitespace in a user drawn image when the user is allowed to erase

Tags: java, android, algorithm, graphics

I have an app where the user draws pictures and then these pictures are converted to pdf.  I need to be able to crop out the whitespace before conversion.  Originally I kept track of the highest and lowest x and y values (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462088/cropping-out-whitespace-from-a-user-drawn-image).  This worked for a while, but now I want to give the user the ability to erase.  This is a problem because if for example the user erases the topmost point the bounding box would change, but I wouldn't the new dimensions of the box.

Right now I'm going through the entire image, pixel by pixel, to determine the bounding box.  This isn't bad for one image, but I'm going to have ~70, it's way too slow for 70.  I also thought about keeping every pixel in an arraylist, but I don't feel like that would work well at all.

Is there an algorithm that would help me solve this?  Perhaps something already built in?  Speed is more important to me than accuracy.  If there is some whitespace left on each side it won't be a tragedy.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are keeping track of the min and max values for X and Y co-ordinates (that also seems the solution you have chosen in the earlier question).

In similar way to this, you should be able to find the min and max X & Y co-ordinates for the erased area, from the erase event...

When the user erases part of the image, you can simply compare the co-ordinates of the erased part with the actual image to find the final co-ordinates.

There is a related problem of trying to see if 2 rectangles overlap:
[Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

You can use similar logic (though slightly different) and figure out the final min/max X & Y values.

Comment: This won't work.  If I erase the topmost point, another point on the other side of the picture could become the topmost point, it would not necessarily be the bottom of the eraser.

Comment: You are right, it may not work if we remove the assumption of edges always parallel to axes.

Comment: Only other option that I can think of is to maintain all points in memory in a different redundant data structure such that they can be quickly added/removed. 
You could use TreeMap which is based on Red-Black trees so it can change lookup from O(n^2) to O(log n) in your case. You could  maintain two maps, one to find min/max X and one for min/max Y.
But you ARE maintaining 3 copies of the same point in that approach. You will also incur slightly extra cost when adding/removing a point, but that itself is negligible(log n). If you could live with the extra memory, this approach should work.